# How do I create a sparse column with a formatted date

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, indexing

I have a timeseries dataset, with the index as a datetime (almost 1 row for every day of a year), I wish to create a sparse series (for graphing) with a string every so often.

```
obs_date    str_date
2018-01-01  Jan 2018
2018-01-02
2018-01-03
2018-01-04
2018-01-05
2018-01-06
...
2018-02-01 Feb 2018
etc
```

I have tried

```
df['str_date'] = df.index.strftime('%b\n%Y')
df.loc[df.index.day != 1, 'str_date'] = ''
```

and can set the first day of the month correctly, trying it the other way around however

```
df['str_date'] = ''
df.loc[df.index.day == 1, 'str_date'] = df.index.strftime('%b %Y')
```

gives the error:
ValueError: could not broadcast input array from shape (350) into shape (11). Is there a way to do this?

Comment: You are getting the error because there are only 11 values where `df.index.day == 1` and you are trying to set those 11 values to  values the len of your dataframe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is the left and right hand sides of your assignment have different sizes. Instead, you can use [`pd.Index.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.where.html) to assign and mask simultaneously:

```
df['str_date'] = df.index.where(df.index.day == 1)

print(df) 
#              str_date
# obs_date             
# 2018-01-01 2018-01-01
# 2018-01-02        NaT
# 2018-01-03        NaT
# 2018-01-04        NaT
# 2018-01-05        NaT
# 2018-01-06        NaT
# 2018-02-01 2018-02-01
```

If you need specific string formatting, you can call [`strftime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DatetimeIndex.strftime.html) on the result:

```
df['str_date'] = df.index.where(df.index.day == 1).strftime('%b-%Y')

print(df)
#             str_date
# obs_date            
# 2018-01-01  Jan-2018
# 2018-01-02       NaT
# 2018-01-03       NaT
# 2018-01-04       NaT
# 2018-01-05       NaT
# 2018-01-06       NaT
# 2018-02-01  Feb-2018
```

Comment: Thanks - that's solved it, need also df['str_date'] = df['str_date'].str.replace('NaT', '', regex=False) to remove 'NaT'

Answer (score 0):

You may check with `.loc` assign with `Series`

```
df.loc[df.index.day==1,'str_date']=pd.Series(df.index.strftime('%b-%Y'),index=df.index)
df
            str_date
obs_date            
2018-01-01  Jan-2018
2018-01-02       NaN
2018-01-03       NaN
2018-01-04       NaN
2018-01-05       NaN
2018-01-06       NaN
2018-02-01  Feb-2018
```